# apply a function over map key

Tags: java, java-stream

I got a function which returns a map.
i want to konw if it's possible to apply a function over the key of the map in order to store function(Id) instead of the key Id.
it would be perfect to do this in one shot.
here is the code of my function :

```
 public Map<String, List<Object>> getMap(final List<Object> listOfObjects) {

    Map<String, List<Object>> map = (listOfObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object::getId)));

    return map;
} 
public class Object {
    int id,
    String msg
    int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

int function( int id) {
    // some code
}
```

what i want to store in the map is function(id) and not the id

Comment: would you mind to provide some example data to explain what exactly your requirement is?

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48584196/edit) your question to add the sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can have a generic utility method that receives the list and a function that transforms each item of the list into whatever you want, and use the result of this function as the key of the map:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, List<V>> getMap(
        List<V> list,
        Function<? super V, ? extends K> keyMapper) {

    return list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyMapper));
}
```

Usage:

```
Map<Integer, List<Item>> map = getMap(listOfItems, Item::getId);
```

This works exactly as your code, except that I've renamed your `Object` class to `Item`, because `Object` was a misleading name that clashes with `java.lang.Object`.

Now, if you want to transform the id of each object before putting each entry in the map:

```
Function<Item, Integer> function = Item::getId;
Map<Integer, List<Item>> mapWithIncrementedKeys = getMap(
    listOfItems, 
    function.andThen(i -> i + 1));
```

This would transform the id of each item by incrementing its value before using it as the keys of the returned map.